# How to configure virtual serial port's baud rate

Tags: linux, serial-port, tty, serial-communication, pty

I created a serial port by using `socat PTY,link=/tmp/ttys0,raw,echo=0 PTY,link=/tmp/ttys1,raw,echo=0 &` I think it created 2 PTY under /dev and let /tmp/ttys0 and /tmp/ttys1 pointing to them.

`% ls -ltr /tmp/`

`lrwxr-xr-x  1 hankboyu  wheel    12 Mar  1 13:22 ttys0 -> /dev/ttys009`

`lrwxr-xr-x  1 hankboyu  wheel    12 Mar  1 13:22 ttys1 -> /dev/ttys010`

Now I want to change the baud rate of the serial ports from default value 9600 to 115200, how do I do that?

Also, do I need to change the baud rate on all 4 file descriptors?

The virtual serial port was created for 2 micro-services to communicates with each other, each micro-service listens on different PTY.

Comment: Are you expecting a difference in performance?

Comment: @stark The communication load between two micro-services is not very heavy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may apply Socat option b115200 when creating the PTYs.

With something like

> stty -f /dev/ttys009 115200

it might be possible to change the speed afterwards.